# On click scroll to div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got this simple setup of images and divs. On click of the div, the website should scroll down to another div. Everything seems alright but for some reason, it doesn't work. I've attached a jsfiddle to the bottom of the code.
Here's the code:

```
<div class="block-2">
        <h4>Choose your coffee!</h4>
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-centered" >
            <div class="scrollcezve">
                <img src="img/cezve-2.png" class="hvr-grow img-round">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-centered" >
            <img src="img/coffee-pot-heart.png" class="hvr-grow img-round" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-centered">
            <img src="img/espresso-cappuccino-machine.png" class="hvr-grow img-round" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="cezve">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6" >
            <img src="img/cezve.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" > 
            <h4>Cezve</h4>
            <p>A cezve is a pot designed specifically to make Turkish coffee. The body and handle are traditionally made of brass or copper, occasionally also silver or gold. Though, recently, cezveler are also made from stainless steel, aluminium, or ceramics. The long handle is particularly useful to avoid burning one's hands, and the brim is designed to serve the coffee. <br>
            The name cezve is of Turkish origin, where it is a borrowing from Arabic: جذوة‎ "ember".
            Other regional variations of the word cezve are jezve and čezve. In Ukrainian and Russian, the word is spelled джезва (where it exists alongside турка, IPA: [ˈturkə]). In Bosnia and Herzegovina, Serbia, Croatia, Slovenia and Czech Republic it is a long-necked coffee pot, spelled "džezva".</p>
        </div>

</div>

.block-2 {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #795548;
    text-align: center;
}

.block-2 img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px;

}

.block-2 h4 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lily Script One', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#cezve {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #C59989;
}

#cezve img {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 550px;
}

#cezve p {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 50px 0px 0px;
}

#cezve h4 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lily Script One', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

$(".scrollcezve").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#cezve").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

https://jsfiddle.net/qpr0vd4y/1/
```

By clicking on the div scrollcezve ( or the image cezve-2png ) it should scroll down to #cezve, but it isn't working.

Comment: did you open your console to investigate? there's a pretty important error occuring.

Comment: It's working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ur5h5t3u/

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado How is it working for you?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qpr0vd4y/1/

Comment: Are you sure you're including jQuery correctly? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGqzrO

Comment: 2 ways: change http for https in your jQuery src, or add jQuery directly using "frameworks & extensions"

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That worked on the fiddle, but doesn't work on my localhost.

Comment: So, please tell us what is the console error in your localhost.

Comment: There was no console error. Fixed in now by using another link to include the jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Then, there was an error, you just don't know how to find it in the console you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are including jQuery in the `<head>` of your document.  The fiddle you provided had it included in the HTML window.  If you move it into the external resources section, everything works.